# toJSON couldn't return TextSize if the TextSize is "Default"

Tags: javascript, node.js, adaptive-cards

I'm using adaptivecards SDK to create card, I found that toJSON() can return TextSize correctly if TextSize is "Small"/ "Medium"/ "Large"/ "ExtraLarge", but if I assign TextSize as "Default", toJson() doesn't return "size" key value.

```
import * as Adaptive from 'adaptivecards';

const textBlock1 = new Adaptive.TextBlock('test');
textBlock.size = Adaptive.TextSize.Default;
const test1 = textBlock.toJSON();
// returns {text: "test", type: "TextBlock"}

const textBlock2 = new Adaptive.TextBlock('test');
textBlock.size = Adaptive.TextSize.Small;
const test2 = textBlock.toJSON();
// returns {size: "Small", text: "test", type: "TextBlock"}
```

Is is a bug of adaptive card or something wrong with my code?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(Adaptive.TextSize.Default)`?

Comment: Id guess default == empty value. Thats on purpose. Size default equals no specific size set ;)

Comment: Hi, console.log(Adaptive.TextSize.Default) output 1

Comment: I think default has value just like others, but I haven't found documentation explicitly state this.